# how to connect to postgreSQL deployed in a server from outside the server

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, localhost

I have deployed PostgreSQL in an AWS ec2 and it is accessible within my ec2. Now I want my Postgresql to be accessed outside the ec2.
this is the command which I use to login PostgreSQL server: `psql -h <host> -d <dbname> -U <username> -p <PostgreSQL_port>`

Comment: Looks correct, what's the problem you're having?
Or what is the error you get

Comment: Is the Amazon EC2 instance in a public subnet? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Besides **configuring your firewall** to allow access to the port you also need to **configure postgres to allow logging in from other hosts**. This is done by adding entries to the [hba-conf file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

You also need to make sure you configure postgres to actually listen on the correct network interface(s) using the [`listen_addresses`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) setting.

Answer (score 0):

you have a change in your command
psql -h  -d  -U  -p <PostgreSQL_port>

here use server's public IP as your  instead of localhost.
Edit `/etc/postgresql/"*"/main/postgresql.conf` :
find the line, `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'`   to `listen_addresses = '*'`        .
then add the follwing line to the `/etc/postgresql/"*"/main//pg_hba.conf`:

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Then restart your postgresql using `sudo service restart postgresql` command.
Remember to grant access to the port of postgreSQL(5432) in security group of ec2.